# Iterating Properly with Custom Function in R

Tags: r, xml, list, for-loop

```
## for individual files
input_files <- list.files("U:/tmp", pattern = "[.]xml")
out <- list()
 
# loop for reading input and writing an output
for(i in 1:length(input_files)){
  df0 <- fxml_importXMLFlat(input_files[i])
  df1 <- fxml_toDataFrame(df0, siblings.of=1, elem.or.attr="elem",col.attr = elem.)
}
```

The library flatxml/fxml just does some xml parsing so ignore that. What I am doing is reading the xml files in `U/tmp`, putting them into a list, then for each element in that list, running the flatxml operation.

The output for each file is a single row (shown in the code as `df0`).

How can I take the output (`df0`) which is overwritten each iteration, and store it as a data frame or list which would grow by one row each time I run the function? Isn’t there some i+1 type of logic that does this?

For reproducibility sake, here is the list I read and process:

```
x
1   SAFETY1007L.xml
2   SAFETY1008L.xml
3   SAFETY10029.xml
4   SAFETY1000V.xml
```

And after running importXMLFlat (`df0`), here is the final dataframe (`df1`) *Notice how it is only 1 row* so the final data table will have 4 rows - one for each element in the list `inpt`:

```
REPORTTIMESTAMP
AGENCYIDENTIFIER
AGENCYNAME
1   2019-06-02T07:08:01.751236  California  Culver City Police Department
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have quite a few options really

1. you can use the `magic_for` library

init

```
magicfor::magic_for(print, progress=T, silent=T) # initialisation with print
for(i in 1:length(input_files)){
  df0 <- fxml_importXMLFlat(input_files[i])
  df1 <- fxml_toDataFrame(df0, siblings.of=1, elem.or.attr="elem",col.attr = elem.)
  print(df1) # important for magic_for as expressed ininitialisation
}
magic_result # or magic_result_as_dataframe() or magic_result_as_vector
```

2. you can make a global variable to append your df to (it seems you try to do it only inside the loop with df1<-c(df0, ) but as you don't save it to a global variable it gets overwritten

   ```
   df<-data.frame() # global variable
        for(i in 1:length(input_files)){
          df0 <- fxml_importXMLFlat(input_files[i])
          df1 <- fxml_toDataFrame(df0, siblings.of=1, elem.or.attr="elem",col.attr = elem.)
        df<-c(df, df1)
        }
   ```
3. you could use lapply/sapply by simply putting

   ```
   result<-lapply(input_files, fxml_importXMLFlat)  # i used lapply for lists - sapply does the same for data.frames
   ```

i am sure there are even more ways to do it but of the top of my head i would suggest option 3